# ajax beginform mvc callback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I have a single page with multiple partials set up. I want to be able to validate and update each partial seperatly. The validation works BUT when I type in a correct value and press save the page goes to the partial view instead of staying on the single page. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my main page :

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
var idTest = "Test_" + i;
<div id="@idTest">
    @Html.Action("Detail", new { id = i })
</div>
}
```

The partial is created like this:

```
@{

var idTest = "Test_" + Model.Id;

var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
{
 UpdateTargetId = @idTest,
 HttpMethod = "POST",
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
};}


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Detail", ajaxOptions))
{ @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Test</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gemeente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label   col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Gemeente, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gemeente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}


@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

This is the simple model:

```
    public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gelieve een gemeente op te geven")]
    public string Gemeente { get; set; }
}
```

These are the actions:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        Models.Test model = new Models.Test();
        model.Id = id;
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Detail(Models.Test model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Comment: Your UpdateTargetId seems to be wrong it should be the div in which partial view is rendered. Try having ID for <div class="form-horizontal"> and set it as target.

Comment: one more thing to note is check what is the value of @idTest after submit. If that value is wrong then it might not just refresh partial view.

Comment: Make sure you have included the unobtrusive ajax script files, see [this post](http://dyball.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/partial-view-using-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-5-loads-into-a-new-page/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines to your view and also use @Html.Partial as shown below

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

so that your main view is

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
@for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 var idTest = "Test_" + i;
 <div id="@idTest">
 @Html.Partial("Detail", new Test { Id =  i })}
</div>
}
```

Scripts would be for unobtrusive ajax so that your ajax button works and Html.Partial so that first time when you load your page in foreach only partial view is rendered (not the full view)

Comment: thats it ! I got the unobtrusive-ajax.js from nuget and that worked.
thanks!